# Adding ufw rules during a preseeded installation

Tags: ufw, preseed, debian-installer

I've been trying to automatically add UFW rules to allow SSH access during an installation of 16.04 while using a preseed file. However, none of the documented methods result in port 22 being open after the first boot.

Specifically, I've tried variations of the following lines:

```
ufw     ufw/enable      boolean true
ufw     ufw/allow_custom_ports  string 22/tcp
ufw     ufw/allow_known_ports  string 22/tcp
ufw     ufw/allow_known_ports   string  SSH
```

But none of them seemed to make a difference. Additionally, my attempts to add the rule in the post-install section failed as the iptables kernel module is not loaded, resulting in an error.

Is this possible to accomplish within the preseed file? Or should I just give up and enable the firewall on boot with a hack?

Comment: I don't see why this would be needed. Default install of Ubuntu has IPTables set to ACCEPT all inbound packets by default already. Is there some other element to your setup that we should know? Does your preseed include installing an SSH server to listen on the port?

Answer (score 4):

I have been trying to get this working for a while, too. Nothing seems to work. Until I finally gave up and I fixed it with a simple rc.local workaround:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
    mv /target/etc/rc.local /target/etc/rc.local.orig; \
    echo '#!/bin/sh -e' > /target/etc/rc.local; \
    echo '/usr/sbin/ufw allow ssh' >> /target/etc/rc.local; \
    echo 'mv -f /etc/rc.local.orig /etc/rc.local' >> /target/etc/rc.local; \
    echo 'test -x /etc/rc.local && /etc/rc.local' >> /target/etc/rc.local; \
    echo 'exit 0' >> /target/etc/rc.local; \
    chmod +x /target/etc/rc.local
```

The workaround will add a custom `rc.local` script using `preseed/late_command` which will:

1. Make a backup of the original `rc.local` as `rc.local.orig` (using `mv`)
2. Then new `rc.local` is created -- which is a script that will be executed on the first boot up of the system
3. The new script will:

   1. Enable SSH access using `ufw`
   2. Restore the original `rc.local` (by moving `rc.local.orig` to `rc.local`, deleting itself)
   3. Test if the original `rc.local` is executable and run it
   4. Exit successfully

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I forgot to comment. I edited the answer here and removed the link, since it doesn't give much more info. Although if somebody wants is as a reference, original gist is here: https://gist.github.com/jheusala/a8862fb9be5bfde6a367eb97fde73c34

Comment: I dont get this answer, first you rename the rc.local to rc.local.orig then, what you did next is create rc.local file... shouldn't u rename this at the end ?

Comment: I edited the answer to include much more detailed explanation about the workaround and what the script does. I hope this helps to understand it @MaXi32

Comment: @thejhh I wonder why we could not execute those command using in-target command.

Comment: @maxi32: Yeah. This is a hack which should not be neccessary. Debian, for example, works as expected using those ufw settings.

However, the newest Ubuntu no longer uses this Debian's installer anyway, so this is outdated info for the 20.04 LTS version and up.